# AWS SageMaker Jupyter Labs and RDS Connection

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I tried using a terminal after I launch a Studio Personal App via `pymysql. However, it always returns timeout. Below snippet is the actual code used:

```py
import pymysql
import mysql.cursors

host_name = 'pass1234'

db = "savvy"
user = "mainit"
```

I was wondering if I needed a VPC upon creation of that studio. Otherwise, connection issue will persist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your RDS is only reacheable from within your VPC, your SageMaker Studio domain's `AppNetworkAccessType` needs to be `VpcOnly`, also the domain's network configuration (VPC, subnet, security-groups, and NACLs) need to allow communication between the Studio Apps and your RDS instances.

You can refer SageMaker [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/infrastructure-connect-to-resources.html) for more info on this topic.

I would also suggest that you use following commands to troubleshoot networking issues: 
`dig`, `nslookup`, `telnet`, `mtr`, etc.